# Ionic 5 white iframe in the app, but working on the web

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

My web application usually shows the iframe when I run the function, but when I'm performing the same procedure on Android it just has a white screen. Does anyone know how to resolve this impasse? HMTL

html

```html
<ion-content>

 <ion-button expand="full" color="warning" (click)="showPdf()">Visualizar PDF</ion-button>

<iframe data-tap-disabled="true" [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(urlPDf)" *ngIf="viewPDF"></iframe>

</ion-content>
```

file.TS

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Sanitizer } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agendamento-perfil',
  templateUrl: './agendamento-perfil.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agendamento-perfil.page.scss'],
})
export class AgendamentoPerfilPage implements OnInit {



  urlPDf:String;
  viewPDF:Boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private sanitiser: Sanitizer,
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showPdf(){
    this.urlPDf =  'https://www.soundczech.cz/temp/lorem-ipsum.pdf';
    this.viewPDF = true;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you inspect the console of android, does it show an error?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try sanitizing the URL
this.urlPDf =   this.sanitizer.sanitize(url)

There could be multiple reasons

1. whitelist policy for navigating the application Webview on Cordova.

Solution :

> ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

Then add the following lines to the config.xml file to allow loading external URL's:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" launch-external="yes"/> <allow-intent href="https://*/*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

2. Alternatively, try Opening it in ionic-native/in-app-browser.
3. Another alternative that works is appending Google doc viewer in front of our URL and passing it to Iframe.

url = 'https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url);